# DB2 packages in C

Tags: sql, c, function, db2, package

I was trying to write a package file in C for db2. But I was just wondering what all include files and functions can be used. I saw this example in this link by york university. It explains a lot but I don't know what resources are available in terms of include libraries and their functions.

Your help is highly appreciated.

http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2012-13/W/3421/db2notes/programs/sage.sqc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a link to the PDF manuals](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024478) -- see the Application Development section.