# sql package doesn't do printf

Tags: sql, c, db2

I have the following code. It works fine when I do db2 prep file1
But it doesn't print out the bye at the end
When I try to run it as ./file1 with a C compiler, it doesn't recognize the EXEC
I am doing this on db2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sqlutil.h>
#include <sqlenv.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlcodes.h>


EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA;

EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
  short sage;
  short sid;
  char sname[16];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION ;

#define CHECK_SQL( code, text_string, eExit)
  {
    if( rc ==0)
    printf("rc was 0\n");
    if(sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
    printf("just checked sqlca.sqlcode %s \n", sqlca.sqlcode);
    if(sqlca.sqlcode ==0)
    printf("well sqlcode is 0\n");
  }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    if (argc>1)
      printf("we have an input\n");
    else {
      printf("please print something\n");
      exit(0);
      }

    EXEC SQL CONNECT TO NAME;
    CHECK_SQL(0, "Connect failed", EXIT);

    printf("bye\n");
}
```

I understand that when I do db2 prep file, it creates a file.C and then I need to compile that file seperately. but there are a lot of linking errors in it. I checked the db2 website and it says that I need to create a dll between the included files.
Help please.

Comment: `#define CHECK_SQL( code, text_string, eExit)` I think you want this macro to extend to the six `{ ... }` lines below it. It does not. Easiest solution is to make it a function (otherwise a `funky do{ ... } while` would be needed)

Comment: It would probably be useful if you post the full command you are using to compile the C file as well as the actual error that you get.

Answer (score 0):

The correct sequence of developing an embedded SQL application for DB2 is this:

- Preprocess (`prep` that you mentioned). This converts embedded SQL into CLI calls. After that you will have two files: a C source and a bind (`.bnd`) file.
- Compile and link the C source, as usual. Obviously you'll need all dependent header files and libraries for that, as with other C programs. This will create an executable.
- Bind the package (the `.bnd` file) to the database.
- Run the executable.

You would have known all this if you took time to read the manuals I referred you to [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578479/db2-packages-in-c).

Comment: Yes I can not link all the C files